# Equivalent of Android's services on iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, notifications, android-service

I'm trying to implement an Alarm clock application for iOS. I have the basics down, like scheduling alarms and the like, but where I'm stuck is to start executing code in the background as soon as the alarm goes for ~ 1 minute / till the user turns it off manually.

Is this possible at all in iOS without the user explicitly swiping their finger to disable the notification and launch the app?

Thanks, 
Teja

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no real way to achieve this on iOS.  The only types of apps that are allowed to execute code while not being the frontmost app are GPS/Navigation apps, apps that play audio, and VOIP apps.  There's an exception that an app can ask the system for time to finish some long running task but this is probably not useful for your needs.